# Unresolved attribute reference issue in PyCharm in doc string

Tags: python, pycharm, python-attrs

When I'm using `attrs` library to create class, *docstring* in PyCharm shows a linting error **unresolved attribute reference**.

On the other hand when I create class normally with `__init__` method. It shows no such error.

I can't figure out this error is generated due to `attrs` or PyCharm because `attrs` by default has all necessary stubs for mypy type checking. While using `attrs`, I could not find any linting errors so far except for this time in the docstrings.

```py
import attr


@attr.s
class UsingAttrs:
    """
    class created using attrs shows linting error.

    Attributes
    ----------
    attribute_with_attr : str
    """
    attribute_with_attr: str = attr.ib(default='some_string_value')


class NotUsingAttrs:
    """
    class created normally does not show linting error.

    Attributes
    ----------
    attribute_without_attr : str
    """
    attribute_without_attr: str

    def __init__(self, param='some string value'):
        self.attribute_without_attr = param
```

Linting error is shown in the image attached below --

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28549

Comment: @user2235698, just upvoted. I wonder it's been two years and hasn't been fixed yet !

Comment: FYI the issue is now marked as resolved and due for release in PyCharm 2022.2.2 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in PyCharm. `attrs` can't do anything about their analysis, especially given the fact it's entirely their feature to check docstrings. AFAIK they don't use mypy internally at all and have to reimplement everything themselves.

P.S. You can write just `attribute_with_attr: str = "some_string_value"` if you use `@attr.s(auto_attrib=True)`